# Disable NIC on CentOS

Tags: networking, centos

I have a server running on CentOS 6.5, the server have 2 NICs, and it happen sometimes when I reboot to pickup the a different NIC, I am trying to completely disable eth0 and the NIC linked to it.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:**:**:**:**  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
              Interrupt:16 Memory:fd5e0000-fd600000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:**:**:**:**  
          inet addr:192.168.**.**  Bcast:192.168.**.**  Mask:255.255.***.**
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35577 errors:20 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:17
          TX packets:18100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41853209 (39.9 MiB)  TX bytes:1568947 (1.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fdee0000-fdf00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 b)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.  Change:

```
ONBOOT=no
```

The "no" will mean "This device should not be activated at boot-time."

For your reference:  https://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-rg-en-7.2/ch-networkscripts.html